# documentService.CreateWorkItem(workItem, a) shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: tfs

I am trying to modify workitem fields and launch it pragmatically WO saving.
Below is code

```
ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "paswd", "domain");

        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("path "), credentials);

        WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();


        WorkItemTypeCollection workItemTypes = workItemStore.Projects["project"].WorkItemTypes;

        WorkItemType workItemType = workItemTypes["Bug"];

        var workItem = new WorkItem(workItemType)
        {
            Title = "Test",
        };


        workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"].Value = "2";
        workItem.Description = "New Description";

        documentService = (DocumentService)_applicationObject.DTE.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.DocumentService");

        var a = new object();

        IWorkItemDocument workItemDocument = documentService.CreateWorkItem(workItem, a);

       (Throws exception : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in above line)


        documentService.ShowWorkItem(workItemDocument);
```

Please suggest how to deal with exception

Thanks and regards,
Chandra